# Adding Additional Y-Axis in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following (x0,y0) data that I have plotted (the y0-axis plotted on the left-hand side):

```
x0,y0
-----
500,1
200,3
...
```

Further, I have another set of data (x1,y1) given as:

```
x1 y1
-----
1.5,1
3.2,2
...
```

I am wanting to add an addition y1-axis on the right-hand side, which will have x1 as the break points and y1 as the labels. x1 and y0 are on the same scale, but the two datasets are of different lengths, and there is no formula which one can use to derive x1 from y0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. Is it something like this?

```
df1 <- data_frame(x0 = c(500, 300),
              y0 = c(1, 3))

df2 <- data_frame(x1 = c(1.5, 3.2),
                  y1 = c(1, 2))

ggplot(df1, aes(x0, y0)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.5,0.5),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = . ~ ., 
                                         breaks = df2$x1, labels = df2$y1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just one syntax error: 'data_frame', I think should be 'data.frame'.

Comment: `data_frame` is exported from `tibble` and `dplyr` in the `tidyverse` of packages, of which `ggplot2` is a part. I just forgot to include the `library` statement at the top.